# Affine regular irreducible surface whose coordinate ring is not UFD

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In Mumford's book *Lectures on curves on an algebraic surface*, there is a proposition above Picard group on Lecture 13:

> For a projective non-singular surface $F$, assume that
> (i)$H\subset F$ is an irreducible curve, 
> (ii) $F-H$ is affine, 
> (iii)$\Gamma(F-H,\mathcal{O}_F)$ is a UFD.
> Then Pic($F$) is an infinite cyclic group generated by the image $h$ of $H$; and Pic($F$)$\cong$ Num($F$).

I want to show that the condition (iii) is valuable， i.e., I want to find an affine non-singular surface $F=\text{Spec }(A)$, where $A$ is not UFD, but it is too hard for me. So I want to know whether such $A$ exists? Thank!

Answer (score 1):

The variety $F=V(XY+Z^2-1)$ over an algebraically closed field $k$ of characteristic different from $2$ is smooth over $k$. This is not a UFD since $XY=(1-Z)(1+Z)$.